# Clipping raster by grid cell using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, clip

I have a raster image which needs to be clipped to be 512x512 pixels.

How can I set in ArcGIS Pro x,y limits to get this clip?

My file has 1500 rows and 1000 columns.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The raster clip tool in ArcGis AcrToolbox might be helpful:
Data Management > Raster > Raster Processing > Clip

You can creat a 512x512 polygon to use as "Output Extent".
Or set the "Rectangle X-minimum/maximum Y-minimum/maximum" to make it 512x512 square. It's difficult to provide the specific numbers without knowing your data range and what part of the raster you want to clip.